# Fatal signal 11, code 1 crash - Emulator only

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm getting the following crash after opening and closing a few activities. This only seems to happen on the emulator. Any insight to what this log is telling me?

**EDIT**: This is happening using the x86 Kit Kat Google API emulator with HAXM in case that's of relevance.

```
03-26 12:14:52.679    2498-2555/com.my.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x65726f43 (code=1), thread 2555 (Thread-140)
03-26 12:14:52.689      924-924/? W/SurfaceFlinger﹕ couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
03-26 12:14:52.799      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-26 12:14:52.799      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/google_sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/1082983:eng/test-keys'
03-26 12:14:52.799      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
03-26 12:14:52.799      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 2498, tid: 2555, name: Thread-140  >>> com.my.app <<<
03-26 12:14:52.799      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 65726f43
03-26 12:14:52.919      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr 65726f43:
03-26 12:14:52.919      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map below)
03-26 12:14:52.919      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
03-26 12:14:52.919      922-922/? I/DEBUG﹕ a39bb000-a3c7a000 r-- /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
```

Comment: I wonder if this happens when you allocate less RAM in HAXM than the emulator is configured to use... will have to check this out later.

Comment: Have you figured this out already? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Guilherme I haven't. Are you using HAXM by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am. Does it work with regular ARM emulation? I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Do you remember when setting up HAXM how much RAM you allocated? Do you know how that compares to how much RAM your emulator virtualizes? I've been using Genymotion for my emulator needs.

Comment: I believe I set it to 1024 MB, and the emulator is set just like that too.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I never investigated further. I've tested on a slew of real devices and haven't had any issues.

Comment: I've just tested on an ARM emulator (yes, it is that slow). No crashes, no errors, no problems. I had tested on a second-hand fake Galaxy S3 running Gingerbread without problems too, but I don't trust this device for obvious reasons. It feels like it's a HAXM/x86 problem.